# LeanTween : How to check if gameObject is destroyed?

Tags: unity

I am trying to animate a `gameObject` using `LeanTween` which has got destroyed already.

The `MissingReferenceException` occurs in `LeanTween.setOnUpdate();`

The null check doesn't work either: `(gameObject != null)`

I have used `LeanTween.cancel(gameObject,false);` but it still throws an exception.

Comment: You can check if a gameobject is active or not in the hierarchy with,
 (gameObjectName.activeInHierarchy == true)

Answer (score 0):

Null check does not work for `gameobjects` so using is null or is object is a better idea. Never check monobehaviors with `!= null`